# Magento 2 / How to change to Camel Case an input in checkout form in real time?

Tags: magento2, checkout, jquery

I need to change to Camel Case the customer input name in checkout form in real time. Have Magento any method for this in Layout Processor or using JQuery?

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to convert the input field's value to Camel Case as the customer types. To do this, you can add a JavaScript file to your checkout page that listens for changes to the input field and converts the value to Camel Case.

Here's the code

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        $('#input-field-id').on('input', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            val = val.replace(/\b\w/g, function(l){ return l.toUpperCase(); });
            $(this).val(val);
        });
    }
});
```